# Regular expression returns only one match

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a set of keywords. Any keyword can contain a space symbol `['one', 'one two']`. I generate a regexp from these kyewords like this `/\b(?i:one|one\ two|three)\b/`. Full example below:

```
keywords = ['one', 'one two', 'three']
re = /\b(?i:#{ Regexp.union(keywords).source })\b/
text = 'Some word one and one two other word'
text.downcase.scan(re)
```

the result of this code is

```
=> ["one", "one"]
```

How to find match of the second keyword `one two` and get result like this?

```
=> ["one", "one two"]
```

Comment: Change the order of alternations from longest to shortest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexes are eager to match. Once they find a match, they don't try to find another possibly longer one (with one important exception).

`/\b(?i:one|one\ two|three)\b/` is never going to match `one two` because it will always match `one` first. You'd need `/\b(?i:one two|one|three)\b/` so it tries `one two` first. Probably the simplest way to automate this is to sort by the longest keywords first.

```
keywords = ['one', 'one two', 'three']
re = Regexp.union(keywords.sort { |a,b| b.length <=> a.length }).source
re = /\b#{re}\b/i;
text = 'Some word one and one two other word'
puts text.scan(re)
```

Note that I set the whole regex to be case-insensitive, easier to read than `(?:...)`, and that downcasing the string is redundant.

---

The exception is [repetition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Repetition) like `+`, `*` and friends. They are *greedy* by default. `.+` is going to match as many characters as it can. That's greedy. You can make it lazy, to match the first thing it sees, with a `?`. `.+?` will match a single character.

```
"A foot of fools".match(/(.*foo)/);  # matches "A foot of foo"
"A foot of fools".match(/(.*?foo)/);  # matches "A foo"
```

Answer (score 4):

The point is that `\bone\b` matches `one` in `one two` and since this branch appears before `one two` branch, it "wins" (see [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)).

You need to sort the keyword array in a descending order before building a regex. It will then look like

```
(?-mix:\b(?i:three|one\ two|one)\b)
```

This way the longer `one two` will be before the shorter `one` and will get matched.

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/rlXYGl):

```
keywords = ['one', 'one two', 'three']
keywords = keywords.dup.sort.reverse
re = /\b(?i:#{ Regexp.union(keywords).source })\b/
text = 'Some word one and one two other word'
puts text.downcase.scan(re)
# => [ one, one two ]
```

Comment: Note that this works because `"AB" > "A"` no matter what "B" is. [*If the strings are of different lengths, and the strings are equal when compared up to the shortest length, then the longer string is considered greater than the shorter one.*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example by moving the first element to the second position of the array and it works (e.g. http://rubular.com/r/4F2Hc46wHT).

In fact, it looks like the first keyword "overlaps" the second.

This response may be unhelpful if you can't change keywords order.